How to close SPL token account in Python
I have accounts that need to be closed through a Python code. I used to manually use the site https://soldustvacuum.app/, but there are two drawbacks. Firstly, when I have many wallets, it takes a very long time to close these accounts on each of them, and secondly, this site has a commission, which is very sad.
I have a code on Python, but for some reason it doesn't work, it just doesn't close accounts and always returns this instead of a signature:
1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
My python code:
import base64
import json

from solana.rpc.api import Client
from solana.rpc.types import TokenAccountOpts
from solders.hash import Hash
from solders.instruction import Instruction
from solders.message import Message
from solana.transaction import Transaction
from solders.pubkey import Pubkey
from spl.token.constants import TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID
from spl.token.instructions import close_account, CloseAccountParams
from solders.keypair import Keypair


def chunks(array, chunk_size=10):
    """Split an array into chunks of length `chunk_size`."""
    for i in range(0, len(array), chunk_size):
        yield array[i:i + chunk_size]

def parse_token_account_data(data):
    # Normally, you'd decode the base64 data and parse it according to the SPL Token standard.
    # This is a placeholder function.
    decoded_data = base64.b64decode(data[0])
    # Implement the decoding based on SPL Token account structure.
    # This is a simplified placeholder for real parsing logic.
    print(int.from_bytes(decoded_data[-8:], "little"))
    return {
        "tokenAmount": {
            "uiAmount": int.from_bytes(decoded_data[-8:], "little")  # Simplified parsing logic
        }
    }

# Initialize connection and wallet
connection = Client("rpc")
wallet = Keypair.from_base58_string("private key")
wallet_pubkey = wallet.pubkey()

# Get all token accounts for the wallet
token_accounts = json.loads(connection.get_token_accounts_by_owner(wallet_pubkey, opts=TokenAccountOpts(program_id=TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID)).to_json())

# Parse and filter accounts with zero balance
filtered_accounts = [
    account for account in token_accounts['result']['value']
    if parse_token_account_data(account['account']['data'])['tokenAmount']['uiAmount'] == 0
]
print(filtered_accounts)


transactions = []
for chunk in chunks(filtered_accounts):
    for account in chunk:
        account_pubkey = Pubkey.from_string(account['pubkey'])
        print(TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID)
        params = CloseAccountParams(
            account=account_pubkey, dest=wallet.pubkey(), owner=wallet.pubkey(), program_id=TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID)
        print(type(close_account(params)))

        recent_blockhash = json.loads(connection.get_latest_blockhash().to_json())["result"]["value"]["blockhash"]
        print(recent_blockhash)
        tx = Transaction(recent_blockhash=Hash.from_string(recent_blockhash), fee_payer=wallet.pubkey(),
                         instructions=[close_account(params)])
        print(tx.signatures[0])

        transactions.append(tx.signatures[0])




The signature appears as 111111.... because it isn't actually signed -- those ones correspond to an array of zeroes. Be sure to sign the transaction before sending it:
tx = Transaction.new_signed_with_payer(
        instructions=[close_account(params)],
        recent_blockhash=Hash.from_string(recent_blockhash), 
        payer=wallet.pubkey(),
        signing_keypairs=[wallet],
)
print(tx.signatures[0])

Going from the source code at https://github.com/kevinheavey/solders/blob/26f9fcb304b19b89697a86624cd90568b3218e4c/python/solders/transaction.pyi#L35C9-L35C30
